# Excel: Calculate Biweekly Periods and the Associated Number

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Biweekly = every 2 weeks**

I've seen many of the posts online about biweekly calculations.  The part that is not helpful is that they are usually calculating between 2 known dates or using a reference date.

I'm trying to do the calculation without a specified reference date and just use the beginning of (excel) time - 1/1/1900, such that I can input a date and get the biweekly period # it is in and the biweekly start date without having to create a list.

---

**Question A:  Seeking Consistent Biweekly Formula**

Using `CEILING`, I'm getting biweekly periods for a given month, however I am having to use different formulas. It would be helpful if it could be boiled down to a single formula.

For Feb 2021, the applicable **start dates** of the biweekly periods are:

- O13 = 2/1/21  - Start of Feb
- O16 = 2/14/21  - Formula result - calculated 2nd period in Feb

`=CEILING((O13),14)-13` = 1/31/2021 --  1st period that occurs partially within the month; ends within the month.
`=CEILING((O13+1),14)+1`  =  2/14/2021  -- 2nd period w/in month  [in cell O16, used below]
`=CEILING((O16+1),14)+1`  =  2/28/2021  -- 3rd period starting within the month

These dates are turning out correct, though I would prefer a singular formula that could be filled down where that period before Feb starts is a different formula.

---

**Question B:  Biweekly Sequence Number Given Any One Date**

Calculating the biweekly period number for the, 1 through 26 (sometimes 27 [roughly every 11 years]). I haven't found any good info on how to do this, given that the biweekly # resets on the first period each year. For instance, using the data above:

- 1/31/2021 = period #3
- 2/14/2021 = period #4
- 2/28/2021 = period #5

Tried:

`=quotient(weeknum(biweekly start date))` which almost gets right results except on certain years, e.g 2012, 2023 - which happen to have 27 periods in the year, but 2000 has 27 as well and quotient gives the right answer.

---

Trying to figure this out in formulas first (logic and calculations), then will transfer it to VBA.  So if there is an easier way in VBA, I'll take that too.

Comment: Pro tip: people tend to understand completely different things by "biweekly", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txa5ia2w7-k

Comment: Since you have already worked with Biweekly calculations using the CEILING then what else you need,, as you have written Single Formula the please share sample data all about what you want to achieve ! Meanwhile just check my post,,, I do believe it solves the issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve been remiss in following up on my original questions regarding calculating biweekly periods.   My questions were to return start dates for biweekly periods in a given month using a singular formula instead of the 3 differing formulas originally posted and to return the biweekly period number given a singular date.  The goal was to do both without creating a lookup list of biweekly periods for the year.

The following is my answer to my questions as well as a dump of everything I observed about biweekly periods.  I imagine all of this info is somewhere on the web, but better to have it in one place.   All formulas were tested against various sampling of dates.  With a slight adjustment, some of these can be used for pay dates as well.

Some of the formulas seemingly answer the same question, however they differ because the available info given differs or is just a different way of attacking it.  I’m sure there are probably more ways.
Some of these formulas I cobbled together, others were found online, which I no longer remember where they came from.

EDIT 3/20/23 --- [***XLS file with all of this in it***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFBubw99yOgrnlxr0YIBAHcGB_fwIRiM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117212948260223827640&rtpof=true&sd=true)

---

**Assumptions/Givens**

- "Biweekly” = every 2 weeks.
- Biweekly periods start at the “beginning of time”, for Excel = 1/1/1900.
- Biweekly periods begin on the 1st Sunday; end on the 2nd Sat afterwards.
- “Biweekly”, “biweekly period” (BPD) or “pay period” (PPD) all mean the same thing and are interchangeable.
- Within formulas:  “tYear” = the year in question; “tMonth” = the month in question
- Years have 26 or 27 total biweekly periods. 27 periods occur when

  - the first period starts on Jan 1, or
  - when the first period starts on Jan 2 and it is a leap year.
- Months have 2 or 3 total biweekly periods.
- Start dates of biweekly periods are equal to or after the first day of the given
  year or month.
- End dates of biweekly periods are equal to or after the last day of the given year or month.
- Compensation in formulas has to be made when:

  - there are 27 periods in a year
  - a year follows a year with 27 periods
  - a biweekly period crosses years  (e.g. 12/29/24-1/11/25)

---

**Question 1:   Return *start dates* of biweekly periods in a *given month* using a *singular formula*:**
With formula in cell AN17:
`=IF(EOMONTH(DATE(tYear,tMonth,1),0)-AN16<14,"---", CEILING(DATE(tYear, tMonth,1)-1,14)+1+14*(ROW(AN2)-2))`

For Jan 2021:

| *row#* | Column AN |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 20-Dec-20 Sun |
| 17 | 3-Jan-21 Sun |
| 18 | 17-Jan-21 Sun |
| 19 | 31-Jan-21 Sun |

For Feb 2021:

| *row#* | Column AN |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 31-Jan-21 Sun |
| 17 | 14-Feb-21 Sun |
| 18 | 28-Feb-21 Sun |
| 19 | --- |

*Row 16 gives the start of the BPD from the previous month that falls within the given month.
The `IF(EOMONTH…..<14` yields “----“, because months can have 2 or 3 biweekly periods.
Perhaps not elegant, but it seems to work.

---

**Question 2:  Return the *number* of the BPD given any *singular date***

Where the number of the BPD is its sequence number within a given year, usually there are 26 per year, sometimes 27.
In order to use a singular formula, calculate the start date of the BPD that the given date is within:
`=FLOOR(GivenDate - 1, 14) + 1`
Then the BPD #:
`=QUOTIENT(WEEKNUM(StartDate+1),2)`
Compensating for years that follow years with 27 biweekly periods:
`=IF(DAY(CEILING(DATE(YEAR(StartDate+1),1,1)-1,14)+1) =1, 1, 0)`

All combined into one formula:
`=QUOTIENT(WEEKNUM(FLOOR(GivenDate-1,14)+1),2)+IF(DAY(CEILING(DATE(YEAR(FLOOR(GivenDate-1,14)+1),1,1)-1,14)+1) =1, 1, 0)`

---

---

**OTHER (maybe) USEFUL FORMULAS**

Generate a list of biweekly periods starting with a given month (“tmonth”) and year (“tyear”):

| Start | End | PPD# (for "start") | PPD# (for "end") |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Jan-21 Sun | 13-Feb-21 Sat | 3 | 3 |
| 14-Feb-21 Sun | 27-Feb-21 Sat | 4 | 4 |
| 28-Feb-21 Sun | 13-Mar-21 Sat | 5 | 5 |

**“Start” of biweekly period**
`=CEILING((CHOOSE(N(ISTEXT(A6))+1,A6, DATE(tyear,tmonth,1)-15)),14)+1`

A6 = header row; formula entered into A7 and filled down
If CHOOSE yields a 2, indicating the first row of data, it returns the biweekly period just before the 1st day of the given month/year [DATE(tyear,tmonth,1)-15]. (Just for information)

**“End” of the biweekly period**
Simply added 13 to the start date.  (Other formulas for calculating the end date will follow.)

**Biweekly Period Number (1 - 26)** (based on Start date)
`=QUOTIENT(WEEKNUM(StartDate),2)+IF(DAY(CEILING(DATE(YEAR(StartDate),1,1)-1,14)+1) =1, 1, 0)`

**Biweekly Period Number (1 - 26)** (based on End date)
Slightly different formula from the State Date based formula, due to biweekly periods that may cross different years.
`=QUOTIENT(IF(YEAR(EndDate)>YEAR(StartDate),WEEKNUM(StartDate),WEEKNUM(EndDate)-1),2)+IF(DAY(CEILING(DATE(YEAR(StartDate),1,1)-1,14)+1) =1, 1, 0)`

---

**Given a year, return start/end dates of the first/last biweekly periods.**   No lookup list required.

| Given Year | 1st ppd Start date | last ppd start date | last ppd end date | # pds/yr | pd # for Last pd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1900 | 1-Jan-00 Sun | 30-Dec-00 Sun | 12-Jan-01 Sat | 27 | 27 |
| 2000 | 2-Jan-00 Sun | 31-Dec-00 Sun | 13-Jan-01 Sat | 27 | 27 |
| 2001 | 14-Jan-01 Sun | 30-Dec-01 Sun | 12-Jan-02 Sat | 26 | 26 |
| 2002 | 13-Jan-02 Sun | 29-Dec-02 Sun | 11-Jan-03 Sat | 26 | 26 |

**First Biweekly Period of the Given Year Start Date**
`=CEILING(DATE(tyear,1,1)-1,14)+1`

**Last Biweekly Period of the Given Year Start Date**
`=FLOOR(DATE(tyear,12,31)-1,14)+1`

**Last Biweekly Period of the Given Year End Date**
`=CEILING(DATE([year],12,31),14)`

**Total Number of Biweekly Periods in a Year (26 or 27)**
`=(DATEDIF([1st Start Date],[Last End date],"d")+1)/14`

Alternatively…
**Number of the Last Biweekly Period of the Year (26 or 27)**
`=TRUNC((([Last Pd Start]-First Pd Start])+13)/14)+(WEEKDAY([Last Pd Start]))`

**Determine if the Year is a Leap Year**
`=IF(OR(AND(MOD(tyear,4)=0,MOD(tYear,100)>0),MOD(tYear,400)=0),"Leap","Regular")`

---

**Given any singular date, return start/end dates of the date’s biweekly period.**  No look up list required.
Where:  Start <= GivenDate <= End
Start:  `=FLOOR(GivenDate-1,14)+1`
End:  `=CEILING(GivenDate,14)`
Period Number:  = Answer in Question 2 above.

---

**Given a year and biweekly period number (BPD#), return start/end dates for that period.** No lookup list required.
How:  Calculate start date of first period of the year, then add the number of days given each period is 14 days (the product of multiplying the period # by 14.)

Start:  `=CEILING(DATE(tyear,1,1)-1,14)+1+(14*(BPD#-1))`
End: `=CEILING(DATE(tyear,1,1)-1,14)+(14*BPD#)`

---

**Given a month, return number of biweekly periods (or paydays) in that month.**  No lookup list required.
*Most months have 2 biweekly periods, but 2 months will have 3.
How:  Calculate start date of first period of the month & end of the last period of the month.  Determine the days, divide by 14.

| Given Month | 1st PPD Start | Last PPD End | # of ppds in month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-Jan-21 | 13-Feb-21 | 3 |
| 2 | 14-Feb-21 | 13-Mar-21 | 2 |
| 3 | 14-Mar-21 | 10-Apr-21 | 2 |

Start of First Period in Month:  `=CEILING(DATE(tyear,tMonth,1)-1,14)+1`
End date of the Last Period:  `=CEILING(EOMONTH(DATE(tyear,tMonth,1),0),14)`
Number of Periods in a Month:  `=(DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"d")+1)/14`

---

**References and Notes**
https://exceljet.net/formula/next-biweekly-payday-from-date
*Based on Excel start of time 1/1/1900.
`=CEILING(date + 1, 14) - 1`          where date is any date (returns 2nd FRIDAYS)
`=CEILING(date - 1, 14) + 1`          (returns 2nd SUNDAYS)

*My notes:

Appears the (date +/-1) is either to exclude (+) or include (-) the start date.

`Ceiling(….,14)` yields the second Sat (Sat being the 14th day); 7 yields the first Sat.

The ending (+/-1) is because the `CEILING` result is a Sat, but a Fri (-) or Sun (+) is desired.*

The `CEILING` function rounds numbers up to a given multiple (e.g. 14). It works because how dates work in Excel's default 1900 date system, where the first day in the system is the number 1, equal to the date Sunday January 1, 1900.
In this scheme, the first Friday is day number 6, the second Friday is day number 13, and day 14 is the second Saturday. What this means is that all second Saturday's in the future are evenly divisible by 14.
The first formula above uses this fact to figure out 2nd Saturdays (*end of the pay period), then subtracts 1 to get the Friday prior.

To get the odd Friday, use:
`=CEILING(date+8,14)-8`
The formula needs to roll forward 8 days to get to an even multiple of 14 (because the 2nd Fri is only 6 days after the 1st Sat [6+8=14]). Once `CEILING` returns a date, 8 days are subtracted to move back to the Friday previous.

---

**Linked spreadsheet:**
Contains all these formulas + sample date.  Many of the columns are either there to test a formula I created, i.e. confirm it’s right, or to figure out why I wasn’t getting expected results.
The “list” of dates in the XLS are not for looking up dates, but was used for testing formulas, as the goal was to generate formulas that return the right result without the need of creating ‘lookup lists’.  They were useful for making observations where attempted formulas failed.

Answer (score 0):

***These single formula calculates Bi-weekly Dates:***

**:: Caveat ::**

*Since OP has not shared any Sample data or Screen shot therefore, I've shown methods calculates bi-weekly dates in two different situations.*

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Formula in cell Q4:

  =IF(MONTH(N4+14)<>MONTH(N4),DATE(YEAR(N4),MONTH(N4)+1,1),N4+14)

**Method 2:**

- Formula in cell S4:

  =IF(AND(DAY(S3)=1,S3-S2<14),S2+14,MIN(S3+14,EOMONTH(S3,0)+1))

**N.B.**

- Keep cell S2 blank & enter the start Date in cell S3.
- You may use any of them, as per your requirements.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.